# Convert a JSON object to a Map object

Tags: java, json, dictionary

I have a JSON object which look as the following:

```
[{"var1":"value1","var2":"value2"},{"var2":"value22","var3":[["0","1","2"],["3","4","5"],["6","7","8"]]}]
```

(Note: `var2` appears twice in the example and the complex form of the value of `var3`.)

The desired output should be a map object like:

```
key   value
var1  value1
var2  value2,value22
var3  [["0","1","2"],["3","4","5"],["6","7","8"]]
```

What I would like is to convert this to a map object with the first elements (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`) as keys and the corresponding values as the values in the map. In case with the identical keys (e.g.: `var2`) the two values which belong to this key shoul be concatenated, but separated, e.g., by a comma.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: first of all, the String is not a valid json. second, show us desired output and what you have tried so far

Comment: The data I have has similar structure to the example. To my attempts: as I am absolutely new to java I have not tried much up to now, because it is a bit too complicated for me

Comment: so maybe you should get some experience with the language doing more simple tasks before trying to solve this complicated topic?

Comment: @sharonbn the reason is I have to do this

Comment: Is the string actually JSON or similar to JSON? The example you posted is not, in which case you would need to write your own parser. However, if the actual input is valid JSON, you could use a library like gson to process the data.

Comment: @DatamineR, ok, you have to do this. so you want someone here to do it for you? really? you have quite a big rep here and still this is your expectations?

Comment: I suppose it is a JSON object, because until now we have user `get_json_object` to extract some elements from it

Comment: @sharonbn My reputation is in R :-/

Comment: @DatamineR, i was talking about you being experienced in how this site works and what kind of help to expect

Comment: the input string is NOT a valid json. you can use an online json parser to see for yourself

Comment: search for }{ and put a comma between the braces. then it will becpme valid json

Comment: @sharonbn I missed the comma :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an adapter to parse a json. you just need to tell ObjectMapper exactly what type to parse into. you also need a bit of post processing since you want some special processing regarding duplicate keys

you get Jackson from GIT: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

here is a complete solution for you:

```
import java.util.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = "[{\"var1\":\"value1\",\"var2\":\"value2\"},{\"var2\":\"value22\",\"var3\":[[\"0\",\"1\",\"2\"],[\"3\",\"4\",\"5\"],[\"6\",\"7\",\"8\"]]}]" ;
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();  // final result, with duplicate keys handles and everything

        try {
            // ObjectMapper is Jackson json parser 
            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
            // we need to tell ObjectMapper what type to parse into 
            // in this case: list of maps where key is string and value is some cimplex Object
            TypeFactory tf = om.getTypeFactory();
            JavaType mapType = tf.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, Object.class);
            JavaType listType = tf.constructCollectionType(List.class, mapType);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            // finally we parse the input into the data struct 
            List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>)om.readValue(input, listType);

            // post procesing: populate result, taking care of duplicates 
            for (Map<String, Object> listItem : list) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> mapItem : listItem.entrySet()) {
                    String key = mapItem.getKey();
                    String value = mapItem.getValue().toString();
                    if (result.containsKey(key)) value = result.get(key) + "," + value;
                    result.put(key, value);
                }
            }

            // result sohuld hold expected outut now 
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

`{var3=[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]], var2=value2,value22, var1=value1}`

Comment: added comments to explain the whole process

Comment: Thnks sharonbn! Looks very promising, only nee to implement it for my case... I'll give a feedback soon

Comment: I installed the required jars but now get one error: It concerns the line `List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>)om.readValue(input, listType);`and says: Multiple markers at this line - The type com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files..... - The method readValue(String, JavaType) from the type ObjectMapper refers to the missing type 
  JsonParseException
and the part `om.readValue(input, listType)` is underlined red

Comment: you need jackson core jar - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.6.2

Comment: That solved the error! But now no errors are visible in eclipse but after running the script I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.<clinit>(VisibilityChecker.java:170)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:261)
 at my_hive_project2.json_to_map.main(json_to_map.java:17)

Comment: And further: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 3 more

sorry for bothering you!

Comment: get Jackson Annotations http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations

Comment: you should consider using build dependency manager, like maven or apache ivy .... perhaps this is for advanced users....

Comment: Pretty confusing all the stuff I have to install but no indication what is needed... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jackson to convert to and from JSON to Map. Use the following code and instantiate the JSonAdapter class, use the method `marshal(String)` to convert the json string to map and `unmarshall(Map)` for vice versa.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonAdapter {

    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    public String unmarshal(final Map<?, ?> jsonList) throws Exception {
        return MAPPER.writeValueAsString(jsonList);
    }

    public Map<?, ?> marshal(final String jsonString) throws Exception {

        try {
            return MAPPER.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<?, ?>>() {
            });
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: why is the JsonAdapter extend XmlAdapter? what has xml got to do with it?

Comment: I have also to extend by another class, the UDF class as this is a UDF for hive. As far as I know I can only extend by one class. How could I integrate that into this code? Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the code, please have a look into that... Ideally its the matter of using MAPPER.writeValueAsString and MAPPER.readValue methods, Thanks.

Comment: @sharonbn, xml has nothing to do here. "Jackson is "100% JSON" and does not try to imitate or emulate XML. Property name mapping is based on standard Java Bean naming convention (although can be overridden using annotations or custom naming strategy)."

Comment: I dont understand how this piece of code can be presented as an answer. the keys are inside seperate items in the json list. and where is the handling for duplicate keys?